# Why is PHP memory exhausted error inconsistent on image resize?

Tags: php, image, gd, image-resizing, memory-limit

I am trying to figure out a sufficient number to assign `ini_set('memory_limit', '*M')` when resizing images of certain size. What I don't understand while testing, is that *sometimes* I get `Fatal error` (obviously not enough memory allocated), but if I refresh the script a few times, it finally manages to resize the image.

Why isn't the memory requirement for resizing a specific image consistent? Why does it eventually succeed if I refresh the php script (1 or more times) in browser? It is as if PHP partially resizes the image, and caches the result ready to be continued on next execution.

If I assign a high enough value it always works on first execution (obviously). However, when assigning lower values, it still works but the lower the value, the more times I need to refresh script in browser to avoid the error.

**Example code**

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');

$image = 'image.jpg';
$image_size = getimagesize($image);
$resize_height = round($image_size[1] * 1920/$image_size[0]);
$image_create = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
$image_resized = imagecreatetruecolor(1920, $resize_height);
imagecopyresampled($image_resized, $image_create, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1920, $resize_height, $image_size[0], $image_size[1]);
imagejpeg($image_resized, 'image_COPY.jpg', 95);
imagedestroy($image_create);
imagedestroy($image_resized);
```

**Example error**

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 10485760 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 28672 bytes) in */test.php on line 12
```

I can easily avoid the error by assigning an abundant amount of memory, but it's hard to find a threshold value, and I am curious to know why it works like this. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Does this happen with the default memory_limit of 128M? Maybe you can get the image size before resizing and calculate a proper memory limit "on the fly" ?

Answer (score 1):

For each process launched on your server if you memory limit is up to 128MB and your RAM is up to 1028MB (1GB) then 8 process can be in concurrency.

It means that if you consider now that servers have always more and more RAM, 32GB for instance, you can assume that increase memory limit up to 512MB is acceptable.

For my application I increased that memory limit up to 1GB without loosing any concurrency process due to my amazing RAM on my server.

This link helped me a lot in the past to understand that :

[php-concurrency](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-concurrency)

Now for your problem on resizing images you can use this calculator :

[Calculator](http://www.dotsamazing.com/en/labs/phpmemorylimit)

This link quote :

> This simple calculator helps you to set the memory size limit of your
>   PHP processes. This is a very important step when you're about to
>   build some image processing website as you'll need to allocate enough
>   memory to process both the input and the output image.

To go more further always on the link above:

> 4. Background info
>
> Tweak factor?
>
> Guess what? Setting memory_limit is not an exact science. That's why
>   we have "tweak factor", a multiplier based on real life experience. In
>   practice, 1.5-1.6 is okay, 1.8 is quite safe in most cases.
>
> There's a script on php.net to find an approximate "tweak factor"
>   based on your own images. The script runs a single imagecreate
>   function on each image, measures runtime memory usage and gives an
>   average, which is the "tweak factor" multiplier - most likely you'll
>   get a number between 1.5-1.8 too. However, you may add some
>   imagecopyresampled code to simulate the entire resizing process. 
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#76968
>
> Image processing in PHP is handled by the GD extension. Should you
>   have the time to find out why we need the tweak factor, please let me
>   know. **Unfortunately the FAQ doesn't give too much clues:**
>
> http://www.libgd.org/FAQ_PHP#Why_does_gd_cause_my_PHP_script_to_run_out_of_memory.3F

Every image has a "tweak factor" to estimate a memory limit that will be suitable to resize without getting fatal error.

Comment: That's interesting, but it doesn't really answer the question about why the fatal error is inconsistent for a single image.

Comment: I continue to update my question to answer properly :)

Comment: Yep, I saw it :) I could "calculate" memory requirement, but it still doesn't answer the question about why the memory_requirement for a specific image fluctuates, or at least resolves itself after sufficiently refreshing the script that processes the image.

Comment: I continue to read your comments, thanks ... but it still doesn't answer the question. I have myself spent time with a script that estimates memory, including the "tweak factor" also referred to as "fudge factor". This factor is implemented because some source images require more memory than others. However, I am experimenting with a single image ... Even when I set the memory_limit as low as 10MB, the script will eventually succeed after refreshing it a few times.

Comment: The reason I don't want to use a memory-calculator, is because 1) Tweak/Fudge factor kinda sucks. I have myself witnessed for some images that the tweak factor was insanely high 2+ 2) Why set a "memory limit" just above what you thing the image will use, instead of a more-than-sufficient value? The process will only spend the amount of memory actually required anyway.

Comment: There is no known logic at the moment to estimate precisely the memory limit needed to resize image, you called it it depends on the image you have to deal with. I can't explain myself those things, it's odd.